# How to use NSUserDeafults to store integer (Swift in iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am searching for an efficient way to store a "high score" integer in this simple game I am building with Swift in iOS. I want it to keep track of it even if the player shuts down the app, closes it, and restarts it. How should I use the NSUserDefaults function to save this data? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Try searching on google before posting here.

Answer (score 0):

```
//TO SAVE INTO USER DEFAULT
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(1234, forKey: "highScore")
//TO RETRIEVE FROM USER DEFAULT
var highScore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highScore")
```

Answer (score 0):

Save that highscore like this:

```
 let highscore = 20
        let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        userDefaults.setValue(highscore, forKey: "highscore")
        userDefaults.synchronize() // it is not necessary
```

When you want to get the info, you have to "read" the highscore from the dictionary like this:

```
if let highscore = userDefaults.valueForKey("highscore") {
    // do something here when a highscore exists
}
else {
    // no highscore exists
}
```